# Delete old files x days and send email if its done

Tags: linux, bash, email, script, centos

I have a script that works removing files x days and keep the folders.
I'm trying to send an email once its done with the deletion. Any advice? Current script is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /testftp/* -type f -mtime +10 -exec rm {} \;
UBJECT="FTP Cleanup"
EMAIL="myemail@somewhere.com"
EMAILMESSAGE="IT WORKS"
/bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" "$EMAILMESSAGE"
```

Comment: Does that not work?  Are you seeing an error, or what?

Comment: That's `SUBJECT`, not `UBJECT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem: you misspelled `SUBJECT`, but the only problem that will cause is that the message will have an empty subject.

The bigger problem is that `/bin/mail` reads the message body from standard input, not from a command line argument.

Try this:

```
SUBJECT="FTP Cleanup"
EMAIL="myemail@somewhere.com"
EMAILMESSAGE="IT WORKS"
echo "$EMAILMESSAGE" | /bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL"
```

Or, for a longer message body:

```
SUBJECT="FTP Cleanup"
EMAIL="myemail@somewhere.com"
/bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" <<EOF
Message body line 1
Message body line 2
Message body line 3
EOF
```

Comment: It works Keith! Thanks also for pointing out that typo. Cheers!